# R - plot existent levels, not all of them

Tags: r, plot

I'm having trouble on figuring how to plot my data. I've 2 variables, say `x` and `y`, where `y` is numeric, and `x` is composed of labels.

Imagine that `x` is

```
["F1", "F2", "F2", "F2"]
```

But the available labels are

```
["F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"]
```

Then, when I run:

```
plot(x, y)
```

The figure is composed of 4 `x` values (F1, F2, F3 and F4), and it shows 1 point on `y` for `F1`, and 3 points on `y` for `F2`.

What I want is to show ONLY `F1` and `F2` in my plot.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for `?droplevels`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the unused level by reapplying `factor()`

```
x <- factor(x=c("F1", "F2", "F2", "F2"), levels=c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"))
plot(x)
```

[image: plot with all levels]

```
plot(factor(x))
```

or as suggested by gagolews (this solution seems more elegant)

```
plot(droplevels(x))
```

[image: plot only used levels]